# Is installing Windows Server 2012 R2 using .com versus .local going to cause future problems?

Tags: active-directory, best-practices

I know using example.com would cause a conflict, but what about ad.example.com, corp.example.com or internal.example.com?  I have a web .com domain.  Will need to remote in and/or VPN etc.

I am being told that ONLY .local should be used and nothing else.  I am not so certain about that.

Something about self-signed certificates?  And when the server is accessed from the public it will fail?  I don't know much about certificates and need to read up on it.

Comment: Whomever is advising you is wrong. Use an unused subdomain of your public domain. Don't use any made up TLD. Don't use .local. Don't use a subdomain of a domain that you do not own. `ad.domain.com`, where `domain.com` is your public domain name, is perfectly acceptable

Comment: From your experience and great posts here, I think I am going to follow your advice and not the "other"s advice I been given after I already ahd my mind set on no .local.  I do own my .com that I want to use and will use what you suggest, ad.domain.com.  I cannot check this comment as an ANSWER, but both yours and Rex's I consider good answers. Thank you Joe & Rex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.local should definitely NOT be used anymore. Specifically regarding certificates, the public Cert Authorities will no longer renew or issue new certs for .local domains after Nov 1, 2015.